# Requisição OPTIONS não chegando até o servidor

Tags: php, javascript, post, cors, xmlhttprequest

Estou fazendo requisições POST enviando e recebendo JSON em minha API PHP. Quando estou no localhost funciona como esperado, porém quando estou em produção recebo o erro abaixo no chromium:

```
OPTIONS http://myserver.com/my-dir/api/person/exists net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

E no firefox:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://myserver.com/my-dir/api/person/exists. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]
Error: "0"
    onreadystatechange http://examplesite.com/js/app.ec842a5c.js:1:25207
```

No servidor tenho:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://examplesite.com");
header("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
   http_response_code(200);
   echo json_encode(array("message" => "OK!"));
   exit(0);
}
```

No cliente:

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if(request.status === 200) {
      console.log(request);
    }
  }
}
request.onerror = function() {
  console.log(Error("Network Error"));
};
request.open('POST', 'http://myserver.com/my-dir/api/person/exists', true);
const jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
if(jwt) {
  request.withCredentials = true;
  request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Baerer ' + jwt);
}
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Os Headers do Chromium:

```
General

Request URL: http://myserver.com/my-dir/api/person/exists
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request Headers

Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://examplesite.com
Referer: http://examplesite.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
```

Os Headers do firefox:

```
Request URL: http://myserver.com/my-dir/api/person/exists
Request method: OPTIONS

Request headers (482 B) 
Accept  
text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-Headers  
content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method   
POST
Cache-Control   
max-age=0
Connection  
keep-alive
DNT 
1
Host    
myserver.com
Origin  
http://examplesite.com
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
```

No localhost funciona, mas quando mudo para o "http://examplesite.com" não funciona. Não sei qual é o problema para eu tentar resolver, o que parece estar acontecendo é a requisição OPTIONS nem está chegando no servidor.

> up

No servidor se eu coloco já nas primeiras linhas de meu arquivo "index.php":

```
http_response_code(401);
echo json_encode(array("message" => "Not authorized."));
exit(0);
```

Ainda recebo os mesmos erros, é como se a requisição não chegasse nem no servidor.

Faço um teste usando o CURL:

```
eu@eu:~$ curl -X POST http://myserver.com/my-dir/api/person/exists
{"message":"Not authorized."}
```

e funciona como esperado.

Talvez algo está errado no cliente.

Comment: Se não me engano a requisição de seu cliente deve ter esse cabeçalho, `request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://examplesite.com');`

Comment: @AugustoVasques Não faz sentido a requisição ter esse cabeçalho, porque esse é o cabeçalho que o servidor utiliza para informar ao navegador quais são as origens que ele aceita. Mas como no caso do CORS eu tento de tudo, eu tentei, mas não funcionou.

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente encontrei o problema, e era o cabeçalho "Content-Type" que estou acrescentando na requisição do cliente.Não é necessário incluí-lo, o navegador fará o trabalho para você, eles estava sendo o motivo do erro, pois quando acrescento a linha:

```
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
```

Recebo o erro:

```
OPTIONS http://myserver.com/my-dir/api/person/exists net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Quando comento ela, tudo funciona como esperado. Então meu código ficou assim no servidor:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://examplesite.com");
header("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true"); 
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Authorization");

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
   http_response_code(200);
   echo json_encode(array("message" => "OK!"));
   exit(0);
}
```

No cliente:

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if(request.status === 200) {
      console.log(request);
    }
  }
}
request.onerror = function() {
  console.log(Error("Network Error"));
};
request.open('POST', 'http://myserver.com/my-dir/api/person/exists', true);
const jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
if(jwt) {
  request.withCredentials = true;
  request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Baerer ' + jwt);
}
request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Com isso está funcionando, o estranho é no localhost não receber o erro, e quando quando está em produção sim, ainda não entendi muito bem o motivo, o navegador não ajuda dando uma mensagem de erro mais detalhada. Acredito que seja porque no localhost não estava sendo acrescentado o 'Content-Type' por algum motivo e tudo funcionava bem. Mas realmente não sei, enfim, voltou a funcionar após retirar essa linha do código.